# Java making Proxy Socket multithreaded

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, proxy

I've built a java proxy and it works but only allows 1 client. I know that I need to do multithreading which is why I have done that so it opens new threads but I can't get it to work for some reason...

This is my Proxy class:

```
public class Proxy {

    private static ServerSocket server;
    private static int port = 9339;
    private static String originalHost = "game.boombeachgame.com";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("INFO: Proxy started");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Proxy.startThread();
            }

        }).start();
    }

    public static void startThread() {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket clientSocket = server.accept();
            new Thread(new Server(originalHost)).start();
            new Thread(new Client(clientSocket)).start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You need to call accept() and start threads to handle the accepted sockets in a loop.

Comment: @EJP confused me :( put it in a loop but didn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is one thread running a loop that checks the server socket for new connections by calling the accept() method on the ServerSocket.  For each connection, you need to spawn a thread to handle that connection.

What your code actually does is check the server socket for a new connection, by calling accept(), exactly once.  You then correctly spawn off a client thread to handle that connection.  However, you don't ever call accept() again.  This is why your code works, but only for one client.  You also spawn off a thread for a "Server" object; I'm not sure how that fits in.

What you need to change is to run the "server.accept()" statement and associated thread spawning in a loop.  You will also need to make sure that you handle the threading correctly so that different connections don't end up using each others' data.  This may require hooking up your "Server" objects and your "Client" objects in some appropriate way.

Comment: I put in some clarification.  The key is that the accept() call needs to be inside a loop, rather than called only once.

Comment: what should the loop be then? I tried just putting everything in the try-catch section in a while(true) loop but it didn't work..